# What is the meanning of an x-expressing neuron, with x = some protein?

Tags: neuroscience, behavior, affective-neuroscience

I'm studying a neuroscientific paper, and in it the authors state that "defensive behaviors are mediated by a BLA population of magnocellular R-spondin 2-expressing (RSPO2⁺) neurons".

I know that R-spondin 2 is a protein, but what is the meaning of R-spondin 2-expressing neurons? What is an *x-expressing neuron*, with *x = some protein*?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you include an APA reference to the paper in question?

Answer (score 2):

Expressing a protein means that the protein is produced in those cells at a detectable level.

From https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/express

> : to cause (a gene) to manifest its effects in the phenotype
>
> also : to manifest or produce (a character, molecule, or effect) by a genetic process

This is basic biology terminology. I'd highly recommend courses/textbooks in cell biology before neuroscience.